# Ampersands in xml file

Tags: python, xml, urlencode

I have a url that needs to be added as an attribute in an xml file

```
http://www.scottish.parliament.uk/parliamentarybusiness/28877.aspx?SearchType=Advance&ReferenceNumbers=S4W-0898
```

I know that I have to escape the '&' in xml so I tried

```
http://www.scottish.parliament.uk/parliamentarybusiness/28877.aspx?SearchType=Advance&amp;ReferenceNumbers=S4W-0898
```

and

```
http://www.scottish.parliament.uk/parliamentarybusiness/28877.aspx?SearchType=Advance%26ReferenceNumbers=S4W-0898
```

The first url put in Firefox or Chrome address bar returns the correct S4W-0898 item. The other 2 return a long list of items.

So my question is: is there a way to encode the ampersand so it is legal xml, but will work correctly in the browser?

I'm using Python and the mindom for creating the XML file.

Comment: In XML you use `&amp;`, but anything *reading* the XML will decode that again to the first URL. Where are you seeing your problem, exactly?

Comment: Note that the minidom will auto-encode your values as you put them in as attributes or text, there is no reason for you to do so manually.

Comment: OK, I get it. So whatever reads my XML will decode the &amp;. Didn't think of that. Thanks Martijn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see where's the problem you're facing?

The XML will be decoded so `&amp;` should return `&` and your URL will work fine.